# ViewStateException with DropDownListAdapter

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, adapter

I am getting this 500 error:

`Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500`

**UPDATE:**

My Error is actually this:
`System.Web.UI.ViewStateException`

```
if (viewStates.Length != list.Items.Count + 1)
{
    throw new ViewStateException();
}
```

I have been getting it ever since I added this adapter to my site that is shown on this tutorial.

[ASP.NET DropDownList with OptionGroup support](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/DropDownListOptionGroup.aspx?display=Mobile&fid=338699&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=2112464&fr=44)

It loads the `DropDownList` just fine in all pages but when I do any postbacks, regular or ajax is when the error appears. Here is my exact code for the adapter and the browser file.

**Adapter Class**

```
public class DropDownListAdapter : WebControlAdapter
{
    private const string OptionGroupAttribute = "OptionGroup";
    private const string TagOptionGroup = "optgroup";
    private const string AttributeLabel = "label";
    protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        DropDownList list = Control as DropDownList;
        string currentOptionGroup;
        List<string> renderedOptionGroups = new List<string>();
        foreach (ListItem item in list.Items)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(
                list.UniqueID, 
                item.Value);
            if (item.Attributes[OptionGroupAttribute] == null)
            {
                RenderListItem(item, writer);
            }
            else
            {
                currentOptionGroup = item.Attributes[OptionGroupAttribute];
                if (renderedOptionGroups.Contains(currentOptionGroup))
                {
                    RenderListItem(item, writer);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (renderedOptionGroups.Count > 0)
                    {
                        RenderOptionGroupEndTag(writer);
                    }
                    RenderOptionGroupBeginTag(currentOptionGroup, writer);
                    renderedOptionGroups.Add(currentOptionGroup);
                    RenderListItem(item, writer);
                }
            }
        }
        if (renderedOptionGroups.Count > 0)
        {
            RenderOptionGroupEndTag(writer);
        }
    }

    private void RenderOptionGroupBeginTag(string name, HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.AddAttribute(AttributeLabel, name);
        writer.RenderBeginTag(TagOptionGroup);
    }

    private void RenderOptionGroupEndTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.RenderEndTag();
    }

    private void RenderListItem(ListItem item, HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        foreach (string key in item.Attributes.Keys)
        {
            if (key != OptionGroupAttribute)
            {
                writer.AddAttribute(key, item.Attributes[key]);
            }
        }
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Value, item.Value, true);
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Selected, "selected");
        }
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Option);
        writer.WriteEncodedText(item.Text);
        writer.RenderEndTag();
    }

    protected override object SaveAdapterViewState()
    {
        DropDownList list = Control as DropDownList;
        object[] viewStates = new object[list.Items.Count + 2];

        int i = 0;
        foreach (ListItem item in list.Items)
            viewStates[i++] = item.Attributes[OptionGroupAttribute];

        viewStates[i++] = base.SaveAdapterViewState();
        viewStates[i] = Hash(list.Items);

        return viewStates;
    }

    private static int Hash(ListItemCollection listItems)
    {
        int hash = 0;
        foreach (ListItem listItem in listItems)
            hash += listItem.GetHashCode();

        return hash;
    }

    object[] viewStates;

    protected override void LoadAdapterViewState(object state)
    {
        viewStates = (object[])state;
        base.LoadAdapterViewState(viewStates[viewStates.Length - 1]);
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (viewStates != null && viewStates.Length > 1)
        {
            DropDownList list = Control as DropDownList;
            if (Page.EnableEventValidation)
            {
                if (viewStates.Length != list.Items.Count + 1)
                {
                    throw new ViewStateException();
                }
            }
            if (Hash(list.Items) == (int)viewStates[viewStates.Length - 1])
            {
                int max = viewStates.Length - 2;
                if (list.Items.Count < max)
                {
                    max = list.Items.Count;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
                {
                    list.Items[i].Attributes[OptionGroupAttribute] = 
                        (string)viewStates[i];
                }
            }
        }
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
}
```

**Browser File:**

```
<browsers>
  <browser refID="default">
    <controlAdapters>
      <adapter
          controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList"
          adapterType="DropDownListAdapter" />
    </controlAdapters>
  </browser>
</browsers>
```

**StackTrace**

```
NopSolutions.NopCommerce.Web.DropDownListAdapter.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) in ...
   // I'm guessing the issue is here
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +8948774
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2496
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction on how to fix this that would be awesome. Now please don't tell me to disable `validateRequest` because that doesn't solve the problem it just covers it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably already solved this problem or just followed another path, but for future reference.

In `SaveAdapterViewState` you save state to an object array with a length of `x + 2`:

```
object[] viewStates = new object[list.Items.Count + 2];
```

Then, in `LoadAdapterViewState` you initialize a local field `viewStates` with the object array coming from view state:

```
viewStates = (object[])state;
```

Finally, in `OnPreRender` you're ensuring that the local field `viewStates` has a length of `x + 1` which will fail because you saved an array of length `x + 2` and that's what you'll get when you load it from view state.